# Calculating anisotropic cumulative cost using two cost surfaces (uphill and downhill costs) and a DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, spatial-analysis, cost-surface

I have two cost surface rasters, one representing the costs of going uphill (or level) and the other representing costs downhill. Using these plus a DEM and a vector layer for the source point, is there a way to calculate a cumulative cost raster using QGIS?

Since the downhill function can not simply translate to uphill and the costs I calculated vary not just by slope, I can not simply use a multiplying factor.

I need to do this for a continuous surface and not a least cost path.

Comment: Is [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390660/calculating-anisotropic-cost-distance-using-two-cost-surfaces-uphill-and-downhi) from a day earlier a duplicate?

Comment: I hope this can help you https://proceedings.caaconference.org/paper/39_desilva_pizziolo_caa_2000/  It does describe how to handle an down and up friction. You can check if the method suit your needs

Comment: @Vince, No, I made two posts—one for QGIS and one for ArcGIS, hoping I could get some help for either or both.